# Best practice to build html from json / js object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

When I get an ajax response from the API, I get a hard json structure:

```
{
  object: {
      key: value,
      key: value,
      ....
      key(array_of_objects): {
          key: value,
          key: value,
      }, {
          key: value,
          key: value,
      }, {
          key: value,
          key: value,
      }
  }

}
```

Now I make:

```
  function render(json) {
  var data = $.parseJSON(json);
  var html = "";

  html += "<h1>Hello"+data.key+"</h1>";
  html += "<h2>Your data:</h2>";
  html += "<ul>";

  var data_array= "";

  $.each(data.array_of_objects, function(index, val) {
    data_array += "<li>" + val.key + "</li>";
  });

  html += data_array+"<ul>"  

  return html;
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: apiUrl,
  data: request,
  success: function(obj, xr, res) {
      $(".content").append(render(obj));
  }
})
```

I know that I using bad solution, because my code is tangled and hard-extensible.

And i want to separate js logic and html view.

What is the best practice solution for this situation?

Comment: Best practice solution in your case would be to use one of the template engines. For instance http://handlebarsjs.com/, or http://underscorejs.org/. That allows you to separate you view from the js code.

Comment: If you're doing this more than a few times in your app I would say go ahead and use Mustache or Handlebars. Your html is always going to be coupled to your API response data, but this way the templates be compe maintainable and reusable.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a client library. They are many and very diverse.
One that would be a small improvement from this is **backbone.js**, which will give you components, that you can (re)render and models to keep the data.
Another one is the widely popular **angular.js** and of cause there is **react**.

If not using any of these, then doing what you're doing is actually very common. You could also try to go with a minimalistic template engine like **jade** or **underscore templates**